# Alternatives to session variables in Java

Tags: session, tomcat, web-applications, session-variables, session-cookies

I was going through some of the questions here trying to find alternatives to using session variables. I have a few points to make, so I'm posting mine as a new question.

My web application is built on Java using springs. I use plain SQL and hibernate both to do a bunch of database read/write operations. It's running on two Tomcat containers. My requirement is to find a suitable and scalable alternative to using session variables. Currently, I am using session to store a whole lot of transactions. There are two type of transactions, completed and queued and I have two session objects to store them. There are thousands of transactions and each transaction has about 10 variables associated with it.

1. First I want to store all the transactions in session. Reason being I want to avoid database queries until something has changed, ie, any of the transactions has been updated. I have the logic in place to reload the sessions objects when any updates occur.
2. There are not many users of the web application yet so I don't have a big need to optimize memory size to store all the session objects, but it would be definitely nice to have a design which could hold hundreds of thousands of transactions.
3. I have a load balancer and my web applications runs on two Tomcat applications and I am running into issues where the transactions loaded on different servers are mismatching. For example, I sort my transactions based on date - when I browse through different transactions they are not staying sorted on the date. I am assuming one of the servers has a sorted list and the other has an unsorted list. I haven't explored the option for session replicating, and I don't really want to use sticky session.
4. Using cookies - too troublesome because of the big number of transactions and details of each.
5. Using hidden variables or as request attributes - not good since I have to convert every link into a form submit.
6. Custom caching - haven't explored and don't have a big infrastructure to implement it right now.

Are there other alternatives I haven't though of?

Comment: Are you sure you need to cache *anything?* Databases already do a great job of that, which would also resolve your point 3 completely. You can't resolve that otherwise without either shared sessions or caching somewhere else, e.g. between Tomcat and the database.

Comment: My initial query to fetch the transactions is a simple JDBC select * query. Does database cache those results? Even if database caches these, I still do some transformation like formatting dates and names etc. I'd like to maintain the list of my POJO classes with already formatted transaction details. At this point, I'm also considering session replicating.

Comment: I suggest again that you may not need any of this. You should just execute the queries you need, when you need them. By which I don't mean loading the entire table. Then see if you have a performance problem.